# To get Virtuemart to produce a custom downloadable PDF/certificate with the buyer's details on it

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am new to joomla and I have a problem:

The challenge is to get Virtuemart to produce a custom downloadable
PDF/certificate with the buyer's details on it.

Virtuemart already have a download after paying ability, but not for
custom created files/pdfs.

Joomla can also already create pdfs from front-end files, so I assume
it is possible to achieve this.

Any suggestions as to how I should go about this will be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would package this in a custom component, basically you need to:

- create a link in Virtuemart that links to the component relating to the order_item
- check that order_item is paid
- produce the PDF by outputting some page content and putting it through the PDF output of Joomla

I haven't used Joomla's PDF output, it may be just as easy to use FPDF, rosPDF or you could use an existing PDF by installing pdftk (on a VM or dedicated server only)

HTH, Jochen